# How to get from the domestic terminal to the international in Dallas?

Tags: transit, luggage, american-airlines, qantas, dfw

I have a flight from Atlanta on AA and then a flight to Sydney on Qantas.  I booked Qantas flights with points, not realizing that airlines won't check bags through if not on the same PNR. I now have to pick up and recheck two very large bags in Dallas. Does anyone have an idea of the best way to do this? I was thinking maybe taking a taxi from domestic to international.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13704/details-on-the-connection-from-international-to-domestic-at-dallas-fort-worth-d, https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85837/what-are-the-steps-involved-in-domestic-to-international-connection-at-dallas-fo

Answer (score 1):

DFW has van shuttle between terminals, just hop the Terminal Link shuttle to terminal D which is where the majority of international airlines are located.  There is no charge and they run every ten minutes or so.

Not sure how DFW's taxi system works, but if it is a queue and the driver has waited awhile for his turn, he will be upset if all you want to do is drive a few hundred yards to another terminal.

Comment: Thank you- will they help with luggage?  That is my concern as I will have two big bags.

Comment: @robin - that will likely depend on the driver, some might give you a hand, some might just watch you do it yourself.